# I am trying to create table in which there is composite key but getting error that to check right syntax to use near 'CASCADE. MySQL (version-8.0.5)

Tags: mysql, syntax, foreign-keys, cascade, composite-key

```
CREATE TABLE works_with(
  emp_id INT,
  client_id INT,
  total_sales INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (emp_id, client_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (emp_id) REFERENCES employee(emp_id) ON DELETE SET CASCADE,  #error syntax to use near #'CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY (client_id) REFERENCES client(client_id) ON DELETE SET ' at line 6

  FOREIGN KEY (client_id) REFERENCES client(client_id) ON DELETE SET CASCADE
);
```

Comment: `SET CASCADE` is not a valid reference option. Valid options are `RESTRICT`, `CASCADE`, `SET NULL`, `NO ACTION`, or `SET DEFAULT`.  This is all in [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Answer (score 0):

The comment by GarethD solves the problem. Change `ON DELETE SET CASCADE` to `ON DELETE CASCADE`.